# feature layers don't appear in the print result

Tags: printing, dojo, task, arcgis-js-api

salam,
I have a problem when I print my map, when I display the result I find only one feauture of twenty. the result does't contain all features.
I used esri/dijit/PrintTask

```
verifier: function(){ //verifier() is an onClick event of a button
var url= 'the way/arcgis/rest/services/Utilities/PrintingTools/GPServer/Export%20Web%20Map%20Task';
var printTask=new PrintTask(url);
var params = new PrintParameters();
params.map =this.map;
printTask.execute(params,this.printResult);
},printResult: function(event)
{
 console.log(event);
 window.open(event.url, "_blank")
}
```

feature layers which don't appears on the result of print, are those where there URLs aren't  links of map service but a link to java servlets that they connect to the map service(one servlet for each map service). maybe the print task desn't make the redirection, it seach the serviceMAP from the url in the definition of the feature layer and as it's the link of the servlet.
I hope that I was clear... please someone can help me! because I have nooooooo idea of what I need to do.
PS: sorry for my english because I'm more fresh than english.

Answer (score 0):

My fist suggestion would be tack the json request going to the ArcGIS server to print the task using fiddler. Then copy the json from the fiddler and test the print service at the REST end Point if its still giving error or not printing feature layer then it issue with your service. I would also like to known following:

1. Are you using proxy?
2. Version of ArcGIS JS API?
3. Have you tested same application with esri sample print service?
4. Is the service secured?

Please let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was a Feature Layer composed from a feature collection object was not displaying in the printed output. My Url based feature layers printed just fine.

My current workaround is to remove the layer's fields property in the map object before sending it to the print service.

```
//Code to remove the fields property from the proper layer.
map._layers[yourLayerId].fields = undefined;

//Then your typical print task code that follows.
var params = new esri.tasks.PrintParameters();
params.map = map;
params.template = template;
....etc.
```